# javac command not found

Tags: windows, java, environment-variables

I am trying to compile a java program I found on the internet and it says that I must check if javac is installed. I installed the JDK a long time ago so it should be working but I get command not found error:

[image]

how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like the `javac` executable cannot be found because you did not set your `PATH` environment variable to include it. This is a simple fix.

Since you are clearly using Windows XP...

- Right click "My Computer" and select "Properties". (or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>)
- Go to the "Advanced" Tab
- Click the "Environment Variables" button near the bottom of the dialog
- Under "User variables" for your account, there should be a `PATH` variable, if there is not click "New" and create it with the variable name `PATH` and the value as the path to your jdk's `bin` directory (something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin`, it is different between installations so you will have to check `C:\Program Files\Java` for a jdk version). If it already exists but is empty, change it to the path to your jdk's `bin` directory. If it already exists but is NOT empty, append a semicolon (`;`) along with the path to your jdk's `bin` directory.

The value should look like this:

[image]

If there were previous values, it should be separated with a semicolon like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First check if you still have the java compiler on your computer.

Open a command prompt and type

```
cd \

dir javac* /s
```

If it didn't find any files, install the JDK to compile your java program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the environment variables, as mentioned by John T. The built in windows environment variable editor is kind of a pain, check out [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about).

[image: picture]

Comment: Looks more complicated, but maybe that's just me O_o

Comment: Have fun editing a paragraph long PATH variable on one line with the built in editor. This editor splits that all up for you into manageable chucks.

Comment: if you're path variable is that long you're doing something wrong

Comment: Or just lots of development tools all wanting in on the PATH.